# esp8266, Virgin, and connection fail

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I've done the ESP8266, sparkfun, thingspeak forums.

I have contacted Virgin support - he tried but had no idea, and politely shafted me.

I successfully use the code from 
https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/WiFiClient/WiFiClient.ino
with my Virgin (Mobile phone) hotspot, and Optus broadband. I run the above code on my ESP8266, with the included Spakfun service, and also connect to thingspeak and my own WebApi service.

Virgin Mobile (modem) broadband successfully connects once and fails all subsequent connections (client.connect(host, httpPort)).

The connections are not spamming (no cause to be a DOS candidate), yet it seems the connection is being filtered before hitting the sites.

Any ideas or strategies for getting a clear view what is happening?

Thanks,
Nic Roche

Comment: i would try calling `client.stop();` at the end of _loop()_

Comment: Thanks dandavis, I have tried that (and many other variations). That still doesn't explain the different behaviours (success/fail) from the different service providers.

Comment: if the "bad" hotspot takes longer than 5 secs, that could explain the diff.

Comment: There does not seem to be a timeout property that affects the connection. Do you have a strategy for increasing the .connect() timeout?

Comment: adjust around `while (client.available() == 0) {    if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {`

Comment: Thanks @dandavis. That is on line 80. The connection fails on Line 58. The problem occurs prior to your solution.